# How can i fetch contacts from device in my app screen in 1 second? Is there any API for that?

Tags: android, fetch, contacts

I am working on an android studio project where we have a requirement to fetch contacts instantly, without having to wait 5-6 seconds, and taking the user to the contacts app of the phone won't work, as we have to display the contact list in out own app design theme. What will be the best way to fetch all contacts list instantly?

Answer (score 0):

It may not possible to fetch all contacts instantly from device in just 1 to 2 seconds. Because as now most users have on average more contacts and with profile pictures.

But it may possible that first time when you get all contacts you can store it to database and everytime when user open app you can fetch data from it. It may reduce your fetching time. **But make sure to update database for some interval or user open app in background. So your data is updated every time.**

*Happy Coding..*